# Php Loop While Condition = True

Tags: php, loops

I have a php file which basically reads a page using JSON and a variable is returned to it (pending/paid/expired). now my simple requirement is if the returned variable is paid/expired the respective actions for them should be taken and the loop should not be repeated but if the response is pending the code should recheck after 10 seconds. A similar cycle then happens again and so on till the loop is stopped(by receiving either a expired/paid response.

here is the code i prepared for it using the examples i found at various places but this doesnt seem to work correctly.. pls guide..

```
    while($end==0) {        
        $json = file_get_contents('http://old.kbourbaki.com/xlisteningpageprestashop.aspx?yyyyyyy');
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $result=$obj->response;
        echo($result);
        if ($result=='paid') {
            p('Order Successfull');
            $end=1;
        } elseif ($result=='expired' ) {
            p('status = expired');
            $end=1;//ex

    } else {
        d('status = Pending');
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

CODE UPDATED extra '{' removed

Comment: What "doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: are you sure this is working cause i see an extra bracket before else.

Comment: it doesn't seem to read the file again 2nd time(or further) if the result is pending..

Comment: @mim. sorry that if bcoz if removed an if statement there to post here.. updating it..

Comment: If you'd write properly formatted code, you'd see you have a very wonky `{}`-usage going on. `while()` loops do **NOT** have `else` capability...

Comment: thanks for doing that.. do you mean this if else dont work inside while loop??

Answer (score 2):

You have one too many curly braces.
The proper elseif and else block should look like this

```
} elseif ($result=='expired' ) {
    p('status = expired');
    $end=1;//ex
} else {
```

It would help you a lot if you properly formatted your code.

Comment: Yeah will take care of those now.. @Marc fixed it here too, any reason why it doesnt work..?

Comment: Your else block is on your while loop instead of your if & elseif statement.

Comment: Pls check now, that extra { was an editing mistake (updated it)

Answer (score 0):

You close the IF condition before the last ELSE just delete the closing clasp.

```
if($result=='paid'){
    p('Order Successfull');
    $end=1;
}else if($result=='expired'){
    p('status = expired');
    $end=1;//ex
}else{
    d('status = Pending');
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: pls check my snippet now, as mentioned before that extra { was an editing mistake here